# How to remove element from Java Map from within Nashorn JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, nashorn

I have a Java HashMap which I have passed to the script engine. I would like to remove entries as they are processed because I'm reporting invalid keys later. The apparent usual method for removing entries (`delete testMap['key'];`) has no effect.

How do I make this test pass?

```
@Test
public void mapDelete() throws ScriptException{
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>(1);
    map.put("key","value");

    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.getContext().getBindings(ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE).put ("testMap", map);
    engine.eval("delete testMap['key'];");
    Assert.assertEquals (0, map.size());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that you have an `HashMap`, you can use its [Map API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) within `Nashorn`, i.e.:

```
@Test
public void mapDelete() throws ScriptException {
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>(1);
    map.put("key","value");

    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.getContext().getBindings(ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE).put ("testMap", map);
    engine.eval("testMap.remove('key');");
    Assert.assertEquals (0, map.size());
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.