# GraalVM's JSON.stringify is not working as it is expected

Tags: java, graalvm

It seems that JSON.stringify cannot  proccess Map Objects in GraalVM.

```
            HashMap<String, String> obj = new HashMap();
            obj.put("f", "f");
            obj.put("c", "c");

            ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("graal.js");
            engine.put("obj", obj);
            System.out.println(engine.eval("JSON.stringify(obj)"));
```

This is output:

```
{}
```

Can anyone help to fix this Issue?
JDK17 Graalvm 22.0.0

Comment: Does `ProxyObject.fromMap` help? (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67156894/10871900)

Answer (score 0):

That **engine.put** looks like putting the object into context but somehow it is not working. At old answers I see that approach was working https://stackoverflow.com/a/46424798/175554 maybe it was in [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)), long story short we can provide the hashmap easiest and quickest like below

```java
HashMap<String, String> obj = new HashMap();
obj.put("f", "f");
obj.put("c", "c");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("graal.js");

System.out.println(engine.eval("""
                console.log('hey I am in js.');
                o=%s;
                JSON.stringify(o);
        """.formatted(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj))));
```

You can find full working example [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/java-examlpes/tree/master/graal-js)